# Get data onto variables while hovering mouse on Grafana geomap

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, geomap

In grafana , after integrating geomap everything is working perfectly .
Now my requirement is to **get data into variables while hovering the mouse so that I can use it on the SQL queries of grafana.**
[Geomap image while hovering mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aRJR.png)

Tried looking for all the way . But there is no answer related to it

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. The best you can do is to create independent variable and select it.